# $httpBackend handling more than 3 calls

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, httpbackend

I am currently running angularjs 1.2.10 and using karma/jasmine with angular-mocks-1.2.10 for unit testing and stuck in unit test case for $httpBackend.

inside it block

```
describe('sumCtrl'...)
 ...
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope,$controller,$httpBackend){
 scope = $rootScope.$new();
 httpBackend = $httpBackend;
 $controller('sumCtrl',{$scope:scope});
}));

it("should call these http services",function(){
 httpBackend.expectGET('/api/something1/').respond({success:true});
 httpBackend.expectPOST('/api/something2/').respond({success:true});
 httpBackend.flush();

});
```

The above code works perfectly but when I add one more httpBackend call

```
    it("should call these http services",function(){
     httpBackend.expectGET('/api/something1/').respond({success:true});
     httpBackend.expectPOST('/api/something2/').respond({success:true});
     httpBackend.expectPOST('/api/something3/').respond({success:true});
     httpBackend.flush();

    });
```

This gives error on line 4. Unsatisfied Request: POST '/api/something3' .... use $httpBackend....

Don't know whether there is a limit to number of requests made using $httpBackend in it block or something else that needs to be kept in mind while using $httpBackend.

Comment: try adding .passThrough()         http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend

Comment: But won't passThrough() call the original API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a fiddle that should you can have more than 2: http://fiddle.jshell.net/gZS5M/

```
$http.get('/api/something1');
$http.post('/api/something2');
$http.post('/api/something3');
$http.post('/api/something4');
```

Works fine. I'm guessing you just have a typo in your url or something.

Feel free to shoot back at me if this doesn't help

Comment: This helped me. expectPOST() was throwing the error, but when i used when(), the error dismissed. and test cases passed -_-